# JavaEEアプリで部署番号の昇順で値を取得したい

Tags: java, sql, java-ee, jsf

現在、JavaEEにてアプリ作成をしております。

現在は入力欄から入力した部署ID、部署番号、部署名、場所に一致したデータを取得して表示するプログラムですが、
ここに「部署番号の昇順」で値を取得し表示する処理を追加したいと思っています。

自分なりに調べたところ、「名前付きクエリ」を使用するのかと思ったのですが、詰まってしまいました。
ご教示いただけますと幸いです。

（初投稿の為、勝手が分かっていないところがあれば、ご指摘いただきたく存じます。）

```
/**
     * 部署一覧取得
     * @param id 部署ID
     * @param deptNo 部署番号
     * @param deptName 部署名
     * @param location 場所
     * @return
     */
    public List<Dept> find(Long id, Integer deptNo, String deptName, String location){
        // クエリの生成
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Dept> query = cb.createQuery(Dept.class);
        Root<Dept> r = query.from(Dept.class);

        // SELECTを生成
        query.select(r);

        // WHEREを生成
        List<Predicate> wheres = new ArrayList<>();
        if(id != null) wheres.add(cb.equal(r.get(Dept_.id), id));
        if(deptNo != null) wheres.add(cb.equal(r.get(Dept_.deptNo), deptNo));
        if(deptName != null && !deptName.equals("")) wheres.add(cb.like(r.get(Dept_.deptName), "%" + deptName + "%"));
        if(location != null && !location.equals("")) wheres.add(cb.like(r.get(Dept_.loc), "%" + location + "%"));
        query.where(wheres.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));

        // クエリを実行
        return em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
    }
```

```
/**
 * 検索画面のビジネスロジック
 */
@Stateless
public class SearchLogicImpl implements SearchLogic {

    @Inject
    private DeptDao dao;

    /**
     * 検索処理を実行
     * @param bean 検索画面のバッキングBean
     */
    @Override
    public void search(SearchBean bean){
        bean.setDepts(dao.find(bean.getId(), bean.getDeptNo(), bean.getDeptName(), bean.getLoc()));
    }
}
```

```
    /**
     * 検索ボタン押下時処理
     * @return 遷移先画面
     */
    @Auth
    public String search(){
        // 入力された条件で社員を検索する
        logic.search(this);
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ソートしたいなら、`CriteriaQuery.orderBy()`を使えばいいのではないですかね？

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html#orderBy-java.util.List-

Comment: CriteriaQuery.orderBy()使って、簡単にソートできました！大変助かりました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 解決したら、それが分かるように[回答を承認](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)しておいてください。

Comment: これで承認出来ていますでしょうか？

Comment: はい。できています :-)